# How to set cookie in request header for websocket in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, cookies, websocket

I'm using Angular2 and my backend authenticate the websocket request using Cookie in the request header. 
I have created a cookie but it does not appear in the header of the websocket request.

Here it is an example of what I will need to have.

[image]

For now I do not see the cookie while it is set.

[image]

I used this example to create the angular2 service : https://tutorialedge.net/angular-2-websockets-tutorial

Thanks!

Comment: If you are making a webSocket connection to the same origin as the web page in which the code runs, then you can just set a cookie for the current origin before doing your webSocket connection and that cookie will get sent with the initial request to open the webSocket.

Answer (score 0):

Those requests are to two different hosts, `http://localhost:3000` and `teamcall.the-patriots.com`, so the cookies from the first, won't be sent to the second one.